# Ignore submodules for pytest in vsc

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest, git-submodules

I am using VSC with pytest to debug my code. This worked fine until I added a submodule which I used in the past. The Codebase in the submodule has not the same standard as my main module and causes the vsc discovery to fail.

I already added:

```yaml
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "--ignore=${workspaceFolder}/main_package/submodule/",
]
```

to my vsc settings, but it seems vsc doesn't care about the ignore.

This is slowing my progress extremely down because I don't really understand why the discovery fails. I might be something with the imports but the code and also pylance have no issue with the import.

Output/Python results in

```
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

which is in the root structure of the submodule and the submodule is a subpackage of the main package.

Is it better to move the submodule out of the main package and use it as a seperate package?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup works for me in Visual Studio code version 1.70.2.

Make sure that the path is typed correct and check the python output (Output -> Python). There you see the command which VS code actually runs to discover tests. It will look something like this:

[image: vs code python output]

Note that `your-args` at the end of the command is what you defined in `"python.testing.pytestArgs"`.

You could also try to define the folder to search for tests instead of ignoring a specific one. The positional arguments of pytest are used for that.
If your tests are located in the folder `tests` at the top level of your repository, this should do it:

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests",
]
```